# WP REST API v2. filters doesn't work

Tags: filters, plugin-json-api, wp-api

I'm using WP REST API v2 to get posts.

When I tried to open localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts 
in my browser I got json with all my posts.

I tried to open localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?category_name=uncategorized and I got the same json though all my posts assigned to specific categories.

Maybe I'm using wrong filter but I tried to open 
localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/media?post_parent=15 from first json
and got all media on my site instead of one attached to the post

What I'm doing wrong with this?

Comment: The url was wrong. http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/taxonomies/

It is helpful to use this plugin on your development site to get all end points of the API. https://github.com/dnaber-de/WP-REST-endpoints-to-admin-bar

Comment: This plugin is not compatible with wp api v2. I tried url only from generated json. Do you think it generates the wrong url?

Comment: Maybe the other branch helps you, the current development for v2 - https://github.com/bueltge/WP-REST-endpoints-to-admin-bar/tree/Rest-Api-v2

Comment: All routes in the admin bar from this plugin returns the message "No route was found matching the URL and request method". I think is too early using this plugin with beta version the wp api v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer here https://1fix.io/blog/2015/02/28/wordpress-rest-api-media/.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_filter' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
$query_vars[] = 'post_parent';
return $query_vars;
});
```

Comment: But is this helpful for your problem with `category_name` topic?

Comment: No, it's solving only my post_parent-problem